# How can I bind multiple datagrids source using MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Let me show u a **simple** problem with a solution, and then a more **complex** problem without a solution.

**1)** Imagine that I have a Shelf, which has a list of Products. I want to display a datagrid with the Products.

**Solution:** At View, I may insert a similar code at datagrid like this: "ItemSource = {Binding Products}". And then at ViewModel, I create an ObservableCollection property named "Products".
Okay.

**2)** I have **MANY** shelves, and which one has many products. I want to display MANY datagrids one below each other. Each datagrid shows a list of products of one Shelf.

Now, how can I bind to **MANY** datagrids? It can be 3 datagrids. It can be 500 datagrids.
How can I do this using **MVVM**?

Thanks. I hope u understood my question.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have a collection of Shelf called Shelves on your ViewModel, you can use an ItemsControl, or a ListBox if you need selection, and define a DataTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Shelves}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: @Seva Well this would show a list of `DataGrids` according to the items in the `Shelves` collection. The `DataGrids` would contain the data of the `Products` collection. Seems to be solution you're looking for. If not, you should rephrase your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the common approach is to create two view models

```
class Storage : ViewModelBase
{
     ObservableCollection<Shelf> Shelves { get; private set; }

     ...........
}


class Shelf : ViewModelBase
{
     ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; private set; }

     ..........
}
```

Then you can simply create an `ItemsControl` with `ItemsSource = "{Binding Shelves}"` and specify `ItemsTemplate` property so each shelf in the collection is displayed as datagrid.